# SQL Query to get the latest transaction date for a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

The title is a bit confusing but is actually accurate about what I am asking for so please bear with me as I try to explain this as concise as I could.

Basically in my mySql server, I have three tables: customerInfo, loanInfo, and transactionInfo (this is some sort of a loan system).

the loanInfo amd customerInfo has their respective primary keys connected to the transactionInfo as its foreign key, creating a relationship between the three tables. (I thought it would be important to explain how the db works for you guys)

I need a query that will give me the maximum value of date from the **transactionTable** where the **loanID** is set to a specific value therefore giving me the transaction record with the latest date among all the other transaction for a specific loan

I really hope I made this clear.

Here are some of the queries that I have tried which returned no result

- SELECT MAX(date_created) FROM transactionInfo WHERE loan_id = 2;
- SELECT * FROM transactionInfo WHERE date_created = (SELECT MAX(date_created) FROM transactionInfo)

EDIT for D-Shih

Here is a sample data[image: transaction table sample]

I want to get the transaction with the latest date where the loanID = 2,
so the query should return the transaction with 4/14/2019 as the date

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: I've editted the post for your reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ORDER BY` descending and set `LIMIT` if required.

```sql
SELECT * FROM transactionInfo ORDER BY date_created DESC;
```

You can also add `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT * FROM transactionInfo WHERE loan_id = 2 ORDER BY date_created DESC;
```

This should get the latest transaction info according to the `date_created`.

Comment: Your solution worked. I just need to set the limit to one so I'll only get the result with highest value of the date. Thanks